# Why does STL function use node's color to calculate std::map node predecessor

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, libstdc++, red-black-tree

I was looking through libstdc++'s implementation of `std::map` and noticed that iterator increment and decrement functions are not entirely symmetrical. [local_Rb_tree_decrement](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/tree.cc#L95) function (aka predecessor) has an additional clause checking for the color of the node:

```cpp
static _Rb_tree_node_base*
local_Rb_tree_decrement(_Rb_tree_node_base* __x) throw ()
{
  if (__x->_M_color == _S_red
      && __x->_M_parent->_M_parent == __x)
    __x = __x->_M_right;
  else if (__x->_M_left != 0)
    {
      _Rb_tree_node_base* __y = __x->_M_left;
      while (__y->_M_right != 0)
        __y = __y->_M_right;
      __x = __y;
    }
  else
    {
      _Rb_tree_node_base* __y = __x->_M_parent;
      while (__x == __y->_M_left)
        {
          __x = __y;
          __y = __y->_M_parent;
        }
      __x = __y;
    }
  return __x;
}
```

What is the purpose of the first case and why does the node's color affect tree traversal in any way? And why is it different from [local_Rb_tree_increment](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/tree.cc#L60)?

```cpp
if (__x->_M_color == _S_red
    && __x->_M_parent->_M_parent == __x)
  __x = __x->_M_right;
```

Thanks in advance for your comments and explanation!

Comment: "I was looking through libstdc++'s implementation of std::map and I noticed"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I believe that I figured it out.

## Header

`libstdc++`'s implementation of `std::map` has an additional node at the very top of the tree. It is called **Header**, it has its *left* child pointing to the leftmost leaf of the whole tree, its *right* child pointing to the rightmost leaf of the whole tree, while its *parent* is actually the **Root node**. Thus it helps getting constant time access time to the smallest and the largest keys in the tree (faster `begin()` and `rbegin()` operations). The **Root node**'s *parent* also points to the **Header node** creating a *parent* loop with these two nodes.

## end iterator

As it was answered by [Davis Herring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58879195/11582326), this is used also to handle `end()` case of the iterators. The most naive implementation of the `end` iterator would simply contain a `null` pointer. If we get to the point, where the next node would be `null`, that is the `end`. It works flawlessly... until you need to go back. `std::map`'s iterators are *bidirectional* and you have to be able to decrement the `end` iterator and get the rightmost element of the tree.

## Header as the end

Here is where the **Header node** helps again. While searching for the next node in the *inorder traversal*, we end up getting up to the parent of the **Root node**. We didn't come to the **Header node** from the *right* (nor from the *left*, for that matter) child and we return it as a successor. This way it is natural to have **Header** as the `end` iterator node. And this is why the condition for the predecessor computation checks for a node with a grandparent equal to itself. This is how we can check that we are in the **Header** node. This also explains why we go to the right child: **Header**'s right child is the rightmost node of the tree and this is the predecessor of the `end` in the *inorder traversal*.

## Wait... but what about the color

Yeah, the previous part has one significant mistake. There are **two** nodes with their grandparent equal to this node: the **Header** and the **Root**. They are undistinguishable from this perspective. We need to have a separate flag for the **Header node**.

However, every node in a *red-black tree* already has a boolean flag: *color*. And we also have a very nice property of a *red-black tree*: the **Root** is always *black*.

Putting it all together, we can omit additional flag altogether and color the **Header** *red*. This will be the distinguishing property for two nodes with a grandparent loop.

Answer (score 1):

That’s surely to handle the `end()` case—note the nonsensical self-grandparent check and the wrong direction of motion.  And, after all, you can’t *increment* `end()`.  The color check is presumably an optimization to (sometimes) avoid more memory fetches than needed.

Comment: I would understand optimization with self-grandparents, but not really a color trick. Also it is a bit weird that going in the opposite direction doesn't require these tricks.